# List of symbols and abbreviations

Tags: symbols, nomenclature

How can I make a list of symbols when I am using `\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{memoir}` with input-files?

Here is my main file:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{memoir}

% Include all settings
\input{setup}
\begin{document}

%\input{titlePage}
%\input{hip}
%\frontmatter


%\input{abstract}
%\input{resume}
%\input{preface}
%\input{Acknowledgments}
%\printnomenclature

%\cleardoublepage
%\tableofcontents*
%\cleardoublepage
%\listoffigures*
%\cleardoublepage
%\listoftables*
\makenomenclature
\printnomenclature[6em]
\input{Symb}

%\mainmatter



%\input{chapter01}
\input{chapter02}
%\input{chapter03}
%\input{chapter04}
%\input{chapter05}
%\input{chapter06}

%\input{thebib}

%\appendix
%\appendixpage


%\input{appendix01}
%\input{appendix02}
%\input{appendix03}
%\input{appendix04}
%\input{appendix05}


%\backmatter
%\bibliography{mybib}
%\bibliographystyle{unsrt}

\end{document}
```

And the List of symbols file:

```
\chapter*{List of Symbols and Abbreviations}

$a$
$N$
$A$
$\sigma$
$m$

\nomenclature{$a$}{The number of angels per unit area}%
\nomenclature{$N$}{The number of angels per needle point}%
\nomenclature{$A$}{The area of the needle point}%
\nomenclature{$\sigma$}{The total mass of angels per unit area}%
\nomenclature{$m$}{The mass of one angel}
```

and here is the setups:

```
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ansinew]{inputenc}
\usepackage[danish, english]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[intoc]{nomencl} % Nomenclature package
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{textpos}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{ifthen}
%\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{ragged2e,array,booktabs}
\usepackage{nomencl}
\makeheadrule{headings}{\textwidth}{1pt}
```

Do you know what I should do?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to help you when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`. In addition, an example of what you want to achieve is surely useful.

Comment: `\makenomenclature` has to be issued before `\begin{document}` and all your `\nomenclature` stuff is after `\end{document}` which won't work anyway. Also you're loading `nomencl` twice.

Comment: Thank you for posting a working example! At the same time, much of your code does not seem to be relevant to the question you're asking here. Please limit the example to only the code required for your issue to appear. You can have a look at [this guide for how to prune your code](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/a/3225) for this purpose.

Answer (score 5):

I like the `nomencl` package for its simplicity. It may not be a high-end solution but it serves my needs and integrates with `arara` which makes using it ridiculously easy. Just typeset the example below using `arara`.

```
% arara: pdflatex
% arara: nomencl
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{memoir}
\usepackage{nomencl}
\makenomenclature
\begin{document}

\printnomenclature[6em]

\section*{Section using some Symbols}

$a$
$N$
$A$
$\sigma$
$m$

\nomenclature{$a$}{The number of angels per unit area}%
\nomenclature{$N$}{The number of angels per needle point}%
\nomenclature{$A$}{The area of the needle point}%
\nomenclature{$\sigma$}{The total mass of angels per unit area}%
\nomenclature{$m$}{The mass of one angel}

\end{document}
```

> [image]

If you don't like the title "Nomenclature" you can change it to whatever you like by simply doing

```
\renewcommand{\nomname}{List of Symbols}
```